# Call and return two List in same model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i am doing my project in mvc4 using sql and c#.

I have two table in database Mem_Basic,Mem_Details

and two propery models for that are

```
 public class MemberBasicData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Mem_NA { get; set; }
        public string Mem_Occ { get; set; }
    }

 public class MemberDetail
    {
        public int Mem_Id { get; set; }
        public string Mem_Role { get; set; }
        public string Mem_Email { get; set; }
        public string Mem_MPh { get; set; }
        public DateTime Mem_DOB { get; set; }
        public string Mem_BGr { get; set; }
        public DateTime Mem_WAnn { get; set; }
        public string Mem_Spouse { get; set; }
        public string Mem_Web { get; set; }

    }
```

In My model i want to retrieve all data from both table and return a single list. But how i combined this two property models in single one. something like that

```
   public List<MemberBasicData>,List<MemberDetail> GetMemberProfile()//I Know this is wrong
    {
         ............//dbcodes

      return list1,list2
    }
```

Comment: On what column (property) do you want to merge the lists? Otherwise you could create a new class that has 2 list properties

Comment: ya i want to merge this two list and return a single list. Is this possible

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a new class:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public List<MemberBasicData> MemberDataList {get;set;}
    public List<MemberDetail> MemberDetailList {get;set;}

}
```

If you want to merge them you can Join them:

```
var query = MemberBasicData
            .Join
            (
                MemberDetail,
                x=>x.Id,
                x=>x.Mem_Id,
                (b,d)=>new
                {
                    b.Id,
                    b.Mem_NA,
                    b.Mem_Occ,
                    d.Mem_Id ,
                    d.Mem_Role,
                    d.Mem_Email,
                    d.Mem_MPh ,
                    d.Mem_DOB ,
                    d.Mem_BGr ,
                    d.Mem_WAnn ,
                    d.Mem_Spouse, 
                    d.Mem_Web 
                }
             )
             .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MemberData
{
    List<MemberBasicData> BasicData {get;set;}
    List<MemberDetail> Details {get;set;}
}

public MemberData GetMemberProfile()//I Know this is wrong
{
         ............//dbcodes

  return new MemberData(){BasicData=list1, Details=list2};
}
```

Try wrapping your list in another class. This is the best form of returning two list at same time, because there is no built in possibility to return two values.

After that you can access your lists like `memberData.Details` and `memberData.BasicData`

Comment: i create public MemberData GetMemberProfile()
{
  MemberData md = new MemberData();       
  
  return md;
} but in md than not show any property item

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the two lists like so

```
var merged = (from m in members
    join mb in memberBasics
    on m.Mem_Id equals mb.Id // join on some property
    into grouping
    from mb in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty() // ensures default if no match
    select new { Mem_Id = m.Mem_Id }).ToList();
```

Which would give you all items in `members` merged with matches from `memberBasics`, given those collections look like...

```
var members = new List<MemberDetail> {
    new MemberDetail {
        Mem_Id = 1
    },
    new MemberDetail {
        Mem_Id = 2
    }
};

var memberBasics = new List<MemberBasicData> {
    new MemberBasicData {
        Id = 1
    }
};
```

But I should ask, are you making 2 DB queries? If you are then possibly you could consider reducing that to one and do the work at the DB level.